# What does it mean for a web application to be "distributable?"

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, web-applications

To be more specific, I'm studying sessions, and I'm reading about the `<distributable>` tag in the deployment descriptor (for [example](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Clustering_Guide/beta422/html/clustering-http-app.html)). The text states,

> > "...it is possible - for the sake of load balancing of fail-over or both - to mark a web application as distributable, if it supported by your application server."

Can someone provide a little more info/context? If possible, I don't need a full background on how the mechanism works (I'm studying for the Web Components exam), just enough to understand in the context of sessions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml.Distributable)  are some useful lines,

> If an application is run in a cluster without being marked as distributable, session changes will only occur on a single JVM. Therefore, when the user connects to one of the other JVM's, their session will not be recognised, and a new session will be created. This may force them to log in again, establishing a 2nd session on the other JVM. As they switch between the two servers, various other problems may arise.

Comment: Thanks - that clears it up, and poses a new question: What exactly does it mean for something to be running on two different JVMs? (Although I'll do some searching on the topic). Thanks again!

Comment: That means If I am a facebook user and It distributed on several servers ,Once i logged in  I may once connect to American server for one request and  next request may strikes Australian/Indian server,But I'm not logging in each time.